# SMS style Toolbar

Tags: iphone, sms, toolbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text input box like the SMS app on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359603/text-input-box-like-the-sms-app-on-the-iphone)

Okay, so I'm working on a chatting application, and I'm having trouble with creating a toolbar identical to the SMS toolbar, with the expandable TextView and the Send button.

Does anyone happen to know how to create it either programmatically or with the Interface builder?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create this programmatically, and it would require quite some code.

Fortunately, there's a lot of open source components that does just that. Look at [UIInputToolbarSample](https://github.com/brandonhamilton/inputtoolbar), [AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat) or [SSMessagesViewController](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller).

If you would ask me, SSMessagesViewController seems better made.